# Override of instance method form extension depends on deprecated inference of '@objc'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to convert my code (written in Swift 3) to Swift 4, for that I am adding `@objc` where needed. Xcode has done quite a good job to automatically fix them but I am struggling with a few (all using the same 2 methods), where Xcode can't help, it just puts `@objc` somewhere in my code.

I am overriding a method called `navbarRightButtonAction(button:)` like this in my `ViewController` class.

```
class ViewController: PBViewController {
    override func navbarRightButtonAction(button: PBAdaptiveButton) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is where I get the warning saying:

```
Override of instance method 'navbarRightButtonAction(button:)' from extension of PBViewController depends on deprecated inference of '@objc'
```

Then I thought the problem us be in the `PBViewController` class which looks like this:

```
extension PBViewController: PBNavigationBarDelegate {
    func navbarRightButtonAction(button: PBAdaptiveButton) {
        print("Override this method")
    }
}
```

So I added `@objc func navbarRightButtonAction(button: PBAdaptiveButton)` but it didn't help.
Then I looked into the `PBNavigationBarDelegate` protocol

```
protocol PBNavigationBarDelegate {
    func navbarRightButtonAction(button:PBAdaptiveButton)
}
```

I added `@objc protocol PBNavigationBarDelegate` but it didn't help either.
I have no other idea what to do to fix the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `@objc` or `@nonobjc` in front of the `extension`:

```
@objc extension PBViewController: PBNavigationBarDelegate
```

Take a look at [Limiting `@objc` Inference, SE-0160](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md#enablingdisabling-objc-inference-within-an-extension) at Swift Evolution for more details. It contains the following example regarding extensions:

> **Enabling/disabling @objc inference within an extension**
>
> There might be certain regions of code for which all of (or none of) the entry points should be exposed to Objective-C. Allow either @objc or @nonobjc to be specified on an extension. The @objc or @nonobjc will apply to any member of that extension that does not have its own @objc or @nonobjc annotation. For example:

```
class SwiftClass { }

@objc extension SwiftClass {
  func foo() { }            // implicitly @objc
  func bar() -> (Int, Int)  // error: tuple type (Int, Int) not
      // expressible in @objc. add @nonobjc or move this method to fix the issue
}

@objcMembers
class MyClass : NSObject {
  func wibble() { }    // implicitly @objc
}

@nonobjc extension MyClass {
  func wobble() { }    // not @objc, despite @objcMembers
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I think I‘ve also tried this before but this time I cleaned my project (cmd + shift + k) and then it worked.